# entering retrieved datas to database

Tags: php

I have a php form with three text boxes (webmeasurementsuiteId, webmeasurementsId, Id) and the values in the text boxes are retrieved from other tables of the database. Now my task is to submit the retrieved values in this php form named (mapping) to the database. I have created the table with the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `mapping` (
  `webmeasurementsuiteId` INT NOT NULL,
  `webmeasurementsId` INT NOT NULL,
  `Id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

But I am getting an sql error as follows:

```
INSERT INTO mapping(webmeasurementsuiteId,webmeasurementsId,Id) values ('','','7')

ERROR: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'webmeasurementsuiteId' at row 1
```

Can anyone correct my error? plz view my coding in this link http://pastebin.com/LELEhRCX

Comment: Your database requires INTEGER values, and no NULLs (INT NOT NULL); so why are you trying to insert empty STRINGS into these columns? Test the values from these input fields first to ensure that they are integers

Answer (score 0):

try e.g.

```
INSERT INTO mapping(webmeasurementsuiteId,webmeasurementsId,Id) values ('1','2','7')
```

and feel the difference

first two columns are declared as int not null, they can not accept not int and null values